# I need a must-have reference or handbook about the numerical solution of the 3D wave equation

Tags: waves, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, simulations

I'm looking for an encyclopaedic book on numerical simulation of the 3D wave equation.

One that is a must-have reference with finite differences, finite element and spectral methods.

Comment: My experience is that books are written on numerically solving a variety of ODEs & PDEs using a single method (e.g., Randy LeVeque's *Finite Volume Methods* or Fish & Belytschko's *A First Course in Finite Elements*), rather than solving a single PDE using a multitude of methods.